# Can not access apache web page on Virtual Machine over WiFi

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have Windows 7 Desktop (Host) with Windows XP On Vmware(Guest). A Windows 7 Laptop, all three are hooked to the same router. The Network Adapter on VM XP is set to Bridged Mode &  DHCP reservation of the XP MAC in Router. Router thereby correctly assigns 192.168.0.113 IP to XP VM.

I have Oracle 8i installed on XP VM with associated Apache Webservice running on VM.

I can access http://192.168.0.113 webpage from both XP VM Guest as well as Windows 7 Host but when I access the same from Windows 7 laptop wirelessly hooked to the router, it errors out stating CONNECTION_TIMEOUT in Google Chrome browser. 192.168.0.113 took too long to respond.

I can Ping to 192.168.0.113 from Windows 7 laptop but somehow the web server is not getting accessed at all. All Firewalls on all machines including Windows 7 laptop, Windows 7 Desktop Host & XP Guest are off, including the Windows Firewall service. Firewall in Dlink DIR 615 Router is set to Endpoint Independent, the lowest security setting.

I am unable to understand the cause of this issue. Any further troubleshooting steps would be great to know. Thanks.

Comment: You could try curl. e.g. `curl -v http://192.168.0.113/`. It may give you a more useful error message.

Comment: Not sure how it would directly relate, but at a guess, if you haven't installed, you may need the LLTD Responder for XP (Google it).

Comment: Post your network settings, from the host adapter, and exactly what you did with the VM adapter configuration. It sounds like the problem is residing there.